# What do the EU's demands from the U.K. include exactly now that the UK has invoked Article 50?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit, article-50

What does the EU demand from the U.K. exactly now that the UK has invoked Article 50?

Comment: Is this talking about the "bill" that's been floating around the news, or more broadly about what the EU's expectations of its new relationship with the UK are?

Comment: Brexit has not taken place officially.  Brexit has been requested officially.  The actual withdrawal is still being negotiated.

Comment: @Brythan I believe the common definition of Brexit is the invocation of article 50, which has happened already.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg why would that be the definition of Brexit? The UK still belongs to the EU, so it has not yet exited, hence Brexit is still in the future.

Comment: @phoog because this was the point of no return.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg According to the author of Article 50, he mentioned that it can be reversed/ "uninvoked" so I'm not very sure

Comment: @Panda indeed, with unanimous agreement by the member nations, it seems hard to argue that it would have to be the point of no return, even if itcould not be revoked unilaterally.

Comment: "Is this talking about the "bill" that's been floating around the news, or more broadly..." - it is impossible for anybody to answer broadly. The question is about the obligations Britain has to take on in connection with having triggered Article 50.

Comment: Thank you phoog for the relevant correction. It's nice of you , guys, to utilise space in the question to determine what the right definition of Brexit is. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are demands and there are desires. It is sometimes hard to distinguish them. The EU position is set out in the "[EUCO Brexit guidelines](http://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2017/04/29-euco-brexit-guidelines/)" These can be summarised:

- That the UK honour existing financial commitments. (This is sometimes dubbed the "divorce bill".)
- That rights for EU citizens that are resident in the UK are guaranteed, and that EU businesses are not disadvantaged.
- That the UK manage their exit from the EU in such a manner that causes minimal disruption to the other EU members.
- That the UK cannot be a partial member of the single market.
- That the UK may not form a bilateral agreement with any member state of the EU on a matter that is of material concern to the rest of the EU (The UK may not attempt to "divide and rule").
- That discussions on an orderly exit from the EU must have progressed before any discussions of a future arrangement between the EU and the UK can begin.
- EU institutions currently located in the UK to be moved to the EU in an orderly manner.
- That the UK honour its share of international agreements formed as a member of the EU.

There are other concerns of particular nations: the position of Ireland and Cyprus, for example.

Comment: Concerning "rights of EU citizens": It seems Theresa May has just decided: "Indefinite leave to remain" doesn't mean "Indefinite leave to remain".

Comment: In June 2017, Theresa May offered "settled status" (ie. equivalent access to UK state services and residence in perpetuity) to EU citizens who had lived in the UK for five years or more. This was contingent upon reciprocity. The EU rebuffed this offer.

Comment: @Ben: You can ask a question on why the EU didn’t consider the proposal sufficient if you are interested. As it stands, your comment amounts to lying by omission, since it implies the EU said no out of sheer ill-will.